# How to select multiple attributes from an entityClass using Criteria API in a generic way

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria-api

I have a `BaseService` class that has methods for genericly creating, update, remove and find entity classes.

I am trying to create a method in this class that queries only the list of attributes I am providing as a parameter to this method.

This is necessary for performance reasons, because there are entities with a lot of attributes where some attributes are queried all the time, but they are almost never needed (and null).

What I came up with is below, and is working for normal cases. There is however an edge case where I want to fetch attributes in an element collection. When I provide an element that is an element collection to the list, the method will fail with the folowing error:

> org.hibernate.QueryException: not an entity [select
> generatedAlias0.valueTypeSubset from my.package.customAttribute as
> generatedAlias0]

My questions are:

1. How can I get the element collection using the criteria api in a generic way. PS: I noticed that the path is normally of hibernate type `SingleAttributePath` and when an elementcollection is of type `PluralAttributePath`.
2. Am I doing this in a completely wrong way? Is there a much simpeler approach using the Criteria API? I can imagine doing something like this with named queries, but I just switched away from using named queries on the entity classes, because it became unreadable and I needed a more flexible approach.

The element collection in my entity class that I am trying to fetch looks like this:

```
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@CollectionTable(name = "custom_attribute_value_type_subset", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "custom_attribute_ref_key"))
@Column(columnDefinition = "text")
private Set<String> valueTypeSubset = new HashSet<>();
```

I am providing the parameter `List.of("valueTypeSubSet")` to the following method:

```
public List<T> findAllView(List<String> attributes) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Tuple> cq = cb.createTupleQuery();
    Root<T> root = cq.from(clazz);
    List<Selection<?>> selections = attributes.stream()
        .map(attribute -> {
        Path<?> path = root.get(attribute);
        return path.alias(attribute);
    })
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    cq.multiselect(selections);
    List<Tuple> tuples = em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
    return tuples.stream().map(tuple -> populateEntity(selections, tuple)).collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private T populateEntity(List<Selection<?>> selections, Tuple tuple) {
    try {
        T object = clazz.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
        selections.forEach(selection -> {
            String fieldName = selection.getAlias();
            Object value = tuple.get(fieldName);
            callSetter(object, fieldName, value);
        });
        return object;
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException
            | InvocationTargetException e) {
        log.error("Cannot create class instance.", e);
        return null;
    }
}

private void callSetter(Object obj, String fieldName, Object value) {
    PropertyDescriptor pd;
    try {
        pd = new PropertyDescriptor(fieldName, obj.getClass());
        pd.getWriteMethod().invoke(obj, value);
    } catch (IntrospectionException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
        log.error("Cannot call setter.", e);
    }
}
```

This example is run using:

- Java 11
- Quarkus 1.13
- Hibernate 5.4.29
- Postgres 13.2

Comment: [This old issue](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-2253) says that it is not supported. Maybe it is still not supported. Have you tried [Selecting a wrapper](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/entitymanager/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-typedquery-construct)? Maybe you can use the same entity class and pass nulls with [nullLiteral()](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#nullLiteral(java.lang.Class)) for the fields that you are no querying.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. I can try a wrapper, however it feels like a lot of code duplication and separate classes. Also, there are various implementations of some enity classes which would make this not very suitable.

Comment: I tried the wrapper, but it also fails on the element collections.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not a direct answer to your question, I think this is a perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage).

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A possible DTO model could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(User.class)
public interface UserDto {
    @IdMapping
    Long getId();
    String getName();
    Set<RoleDto> getRoles();

    @EntityView(Role.class)
    interface RoleDto {
        @IdMapping
        Long getId();
        String getName();
    }
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`UserDto a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, UserDto.class, id);`

The best part is, it will only fetch the state that is actually necessary! There is a Quarkus integration, so you can even use this with native images if you want.

Comment: Looks interesting, thanks for the suggestion. But I would like to run the query dynamically instead of creating a DTO for every view. But I'll take a look more closely in the future!

Comment: You can request to initialize only a subset of the attributes that you define in an entity view. This is also used to implement efficient fetching within the GraphQL integration. I thought that I needed fully dynamic models in the past as well, but it turned out, that I mostly had only 2-3 representations (drop-down, tabular, detail). For the tabular representation, it makes sense to skip attributes if you support dynamic columns.